# Replace date pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have a list, such as the following:

```
li = {"2017-10-16", 10.24, 10.71, 10.18, 10.61, 10.61, 16802200}
```

Extracting the first element `li[[1]]` I obtain `2017-10-16`. My objective is to change the sign `-` to a comma `,`. I tried using the `Replace` function, however my implementation:

```
Replace[li[[1]], "-" -> ","]
```

returned `2017-10-16`.

How can I change `-` to `,` in the date listed above?

Comment: `li /. x_String :> StringReplace[x , "-" -> ","]`

Comment: @JasonB. that works. Want to put this as an answer and I'll wrap this show up?

Comment: Another possibility: `If[StringQ[#], StringReplace[#, "-" -> ","], #] & /@ li` ;-)